Leaflet Map has just stopped working
I have built a map in Drupal Views using Leaflet and it's worked fine but seems to have stopped recently. I didn't check it on the recent update so it may have been then.

CiviCRM v5.73.1
Drupal v10.2.6
Leaflet v10.2.14
CiviCRM Entity v4.0.0-beta2
CiviCRM Leaflet Entity v2.0.0-alpha1
PHP 8.1

When I check the settings for the Format (top left), in the pop-up window there's a message in red:

Please add at least one Geofield to the View and come back here to set it as Data Source.

The View contains the Longitude and Latitude fields and they have data in them.
Is it possible that a recent update has changed the way Drupal would recognise the lon/lat fields so that it no longer regards them as geofields?
I can't find anything similar in any online searches or in the issues logs for the Drupal modules.

Not that I'm aware of. FYI there is now a mapping extension for SearchKit so you can do maps natively in Civi without Views.

Ah, I did not know this. Thank you, I will take a look!

I've hit the same issue too. Unsure when this broke to be honest.

@RoseLanigan I can confim that downgrading drupal/leaflet to 10.2.13 get this working again.

Nick - you can add this as an Answer and get some + points

Created issue in module queue: https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity_leaflet/issues/3448917
created MR for at least temporary fix: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/civicrm_entity_leaflet/-/merge_requests/1

New release with the bug fix https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity_leaflet/releases/2.0.0-alpha2

New release with the bug fix drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity_leaflet/releases/2.0.0-alpha2
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/civicrm_entity_leaflet/-/merge_requests/1
